# R: Group data frame by time intervals

Tags: r, machine-learning, transactions, rstudio, data-science

I have a following data frame of customer transactions:

```
CustID    TransID    Product    Datetime
1         1A         Milk       19:13.7
1         1A         Bread      19:13.7
2         2A         Butter     20:15.1
2         2A         Soda       20:15.1
```

I am reading the file as:

```
df = read.csv("data.csv", as.is = TRUE)
```

In that case, the `typeof(df$Datetime)` is `character`.

How do I create three groups from this data frame to reflect transaction in Morning, Afternoon and Evening?

Basically I am looking to create three data frames:
    dfMorning
    dfAfternoon
    dfEvening

Comment: you want `?cut` and `?split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If morning is from 00:00.0 to 12:00.0, etc. you can use text comparison directly:

```
dfMorning <- df[df$DateTime < '12:00.0',]
dfAfternoon <- df[df$DateTime >= '12:00.0' & df$DateTime < '18:00.0',]
dfEvening <- df[df$DateTime >= '18:00.0',]
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Out of curiosity, how do I convert time into correct format? I tried `strptime` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

A different solution in line with Sotos' suggestion:

```
breaks <- strptime(c('00:00','06:00','12:00','18:00','24:00'), '%H:%M')
labels <- c('Night', 'Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening')

df <- data.frame(DateTime=c('12:14.3','23:59.9','06:47.0','02:01.36'))
df$DateTime <- strptime(df$DateTime, '%H:%M')
intervals <- cut(df$DateTime, breaks=breaks, labels=labels)
res <- split(df, intervals)
```